# How can I implement shortcode on click event

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, video, shortcode

I am a newbie in WordPress not totally but 6 months. So I am finding the new thing and practicing on WordPress. I want to know that how can I implement shortcode on click event means

I have buttons on my index.php page like this:

```
<button>Video</button>
<button>audio</button>
```

and with these video and audio buttons, I want to attach the WordPress inbuilt video and audio shortcodes and if I click on any of the two buttons.

suppose if I have clicked on video button the video tag appears under the video buttons and when I again click on video button the video the video tag again disappears.

Comment: you can do using simple CSS & JS hide show

Comment: @AnkurBhadania can you give me code help

Comment: You don't need a shortcode. Here's an example of what you need: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_slidetoggle

Comment: Suppose that's what @user7791702 wants to achieve, the js code for it can't be suspended in thin air, can it? It has to be part of a theme/plugin's code then enqueued at least. Suppose php code would also be needed for the implementation, the functionality would have to be exposed in some way e.g a shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if I understand what you want to accomplish with your buttons, but you can totally do that with shortcodes.

The use of shortcodes is one of the ways to expose functionality written in plugins/themes to users of a WordPress site. So you can write code to do what you want then create a shortcode for it:

```
function something_rad_function( $atts ){
    return "Some RAD functionality";
}
add_shortcode( 'something_rad', 'something_rad_function' );
```

You can use the shortcode in a post or page with: `[something_rad]`. Also `do_shortcode()` may come in handy if you need external functionality available through shortcodes.

Comment: what does the expose functionality means here does using the shortcode is not a good idea

Comment: By "expose functionality", i mean execute the code written to achieve what you want. When you write code in a plugin/theme, wordpress doesn't do anything with it until you attach it to a hook. Can you please explain better what you want to do? It was for lack of understanding of your intentions that I used "expose functionality".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Let me explain. Just like visual composer it uses the shortcode on drag n drop event right?. I want to use it on click event is it clear.